# Get the unique number when it detects 'N' flag in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a binary flag ('Y' or 'N') column, from a table, like below:

| ID | prev_appt_flag |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | N |
| 2 | Y |
| 3 | Y |
| 4 | N |
| 5 | N |
| 6 | Y |
| 7 | N |
| 8 | Y |
| 9 | Y |
| 10 | N |
| 11 | Y |

Then, I want a row counter that will only add to its count, whenever it finds 'N'. So for this example, the expected outcome would be:

| ID | prev_appt_flag | final_goal |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | N | 1 |
| 2 | Y | 1 |
| 3 | Y | 1 |
| 4 | N | 2 |
| 5 | N | 3 |
| 6 | Y | 3 |
| 7 | N | 4 |
| 8 | Y | 4 |
| 9 | Y | 4 |
| 10 | N | 5 |
| 11 | Y | 5 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `COUNT()` here as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT ID, prev_appt_flag,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN prev_appt_flag = 'N' THEN 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS final_goal
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: Thank you legend!! It's worked perfectly, I'd been banging my head on the wall for days :D
Cheers!